# How can I create a new output file for each subfolder under a main folder using perl?

Tags: perl

I have 100 subfolder in a main folder. They have difference names. Each subfolder includes a .txt file, which has 10 column. I want to get a new .txt file for each subfolder. Each new .txt file must be in its own folder. That is I will have 2 .txt files (old and new) in each subfolder. I am trying to select the lines starting "ATOM" and some columns 2,6,7 and 8 from each .txt file. My code is the following. It doesn't work correctly. It doesnt create a new .txt file. How can i figure out this problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$search_text = "ATOM";
@files = <*/*.txt>;
foreach $file (@files) {
    print $file . "\n";

    open(DATA, $file);      
    open(OUT_FILE, ">$file a.txt");

    while ($line = <DATA>)
    {
        @fields = split /\s+/, $line;
        if ($line =~ m/$search_text/)
        { 

            print OUT_FILE "$fields[2]\t$fields[6]\t$fields[7]\t$fields[8]\n"; 
        }

    }

}
close(OUT_FILE);
```

Comment: Works for me. Do you really want the output file be called `something.txt a.txt` with the space?

Comment: No. I need to a new output file be called a.txt for each subfolder separately.

Comment: I think the problem is this line `open(OUT_FILE, ">$file a.txt")`. When i changed it like `open(OUT_FILE, ">a.txt")`, i get only a `a.txt` file in main folder. Whereas the each new `a.txt` file must be in its own folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the output file `a.txt` into the same directory as the input file, you need to extract the directory name from the input file name, and prepend it to the output file name (`a.txt`).  There are a couple of ways you can do that; probably the simplest is to use `dirname()` from the standard module [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html):

```
use File::Basename;
my $dir = dirname($file);
open(OUT_FILE, ">", "$dir/a.txt") or die "Failed to open $dir/a.txt: $!";
```

or you could use [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html) directly:

```
use File::Spec;
my ($volume, $dir) = File::Spec->splitpath($file);
my $outname = File::Spec->catpath($volume, $dir, 'a.txt');
open(OUT_FILE, ">", $outname) or die "Failed to open $outname: $!";
```

or you could just use a [regexp substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer):

```
my $outname = ( $file =~ s![^/]+$!a.txt!r );
open(OUT_FILE, ">", $outname) or die "Failed to open $outname: $!";
```

---

**Ps.** In any case, I'd recommend adopting several good habits that will help you write better Perl scripts:

1. Always start your scripts with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  Fix any errors and warnings they produce.  In particular, declare all your local variables with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) to make them lexically scoped.
2. Check the return value of functions like [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and abort the script if they fail.  (I've done this in my examples above.)
3. Use the three-argument form of `open()`, as I also did in my examples above.  It's a lot less likely to break if your filenames contain funny characters.
4. Consider using lexically scoped file handles (`open my $out_file, ...`) instead of global file handles (`open OUT_FILE, ...`).  I didn't do that in my code snippets above, because I wanted to keep them compatible with the rest of your code, but it would be good practice.
5. If you're pre-declaring a regular expression, like your `$search_text`, use [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) instead of a plain string, like this:

   ```
   my $search_text = qr/ATOM/;
   ```

   It's slightly more efficient, and the quoting rules for special characters are much saner.
6. For printing multiple columns from an array, consider using `join()` and a list slice, as in:

   ```
   print OUT_FILE join("\t", @fields[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
   ```

Finally, if I were you, I'd reconsider my file naming scheme: the output file name `a.txt` matches your input file name glob `*.txt`, so your script will likely break if you run it twice in a row.

Comment: Final Code:
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
my $search_text = qr/ATOM/;
@files = <*/*.pdb>;
foreach $file (@files) {
print $file . "\n";
my $dir = dirname($file);
open(DATA, $file);      
open(out_file, ">", "$dir/a.log") or die "Failed to open $dir/a.log: $!";
while ($line = <DATA>)
{
@fields = split /\s+/, $line;
if ($line =~ m/$search_text/)
{      print out_file join("\t", @fields[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
}}}
close(OUT_FILE);`

Comment: `@Ilmari Karonen` Firstly, thanks for your reply/recommends. Your recommends are very useful. I revised the script as you said. At beginning it worked and created the output files correctly. I ran it 5-6 times. But now it gives a error about this line:@files = <*/*.pdb>;.

Error:Global symbol "@files" requires explicit package name at .pl line 9. BEGIN not safe after errors..

I think i must revise this line. What is your suggestion? Finally my .pdb files have a regular format. But the minus numbers has some shift in the output files (.log). How can I get them like in .pdb file?

Comment: You'll need a few more `my`s to pass `use strict`. In particular, `my @files = <*/*.pdb>` and `foreach my $file (@files)` and `while (my $line = <DATA>)` and `my @fields = split ...`. Also, filehandle names are case-sensitive, so `out_file` and `OUT_FILE` are not the same filehandle (and `$out_file` would be different from both of those). The convention is to user upper-case names for global filehandles (`open OUT_FILE, ...`), but lowercase for local filehandle references (`open my $out_file, ...`).

Comment: OK. Now it works correctly.  A question about output files: my .pdb files have a regular format. But the minus numbers has some shift in the output files (.log). How can I get them like in .pdb file?

Comment: You could try [`sprintf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html), as in `join("\t", map sprintf("% g", $_), @fields[2,6,7,8])`. See the linked perldoc for possible formats.

Comment: `Ilmari Karonen` I am trying to create a different naming .log file in each folder(like 1.log,2.log,3.log...). To get different naming files i used "for loop" before "while loop" in my code. But I got two .log file in each folder. What is your advice?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I really can't tell. You might want to ask a new question about that.