# How can I get a different naming text file in each different subfolder using perl?

Tags: perl

I have nine subfolders in a main folder. Each subfolder includes a .pdb file, which has 10 columns. I want to get a new .log file for each subfolder. Each new .log file must be in its own folder. I am trying to create a different naming .log file in each subfolder (like 1.log,2.log,3.log...). But I get two .log file in each folder. How can I get a different naming .log file in each subfolder?

.pdb file:

```
ATOM      1  O   LIG A   1      -4.657  -0.947  -1.014  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      2  N   LIG A   1      -0.173   0.679   0.052  1.00  0.00           N1+
ATOM      3  N   LIG A   1       3.135  -0.678  -0.977  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      4  N   LIG A   1       3.331   0.341   1.198  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      5  N   LIG A   1       1.046  -0.695  -2.103  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      6  C   LIG A   1      -1.086  -0.167   0.546  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      7  C   LIG A   1      -2.430   0.177   0.537  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  C   LIG A   1      -3.476  -0.737   1.080  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      9  C   LIG A   1       1.209   0.327   0.061  1.00  0.00           C 
ATOM     10  C   LIG A   1      -2.803   1.409   0.008  1.00  0.00           C
```

.log file:

```
O   -4.657  -0.947  -1.014
N   -0.173  0.679   0.052
N   3.135   -0.678  -0.977
N   3.331   0.341   1.198
N   1.046   -0.695  -2.103
C   -1.086  -0.167  0.546
C   -2.430  0.177   0.537
C   -3.476  -0.737  1.080
C   1.209   0.327   0.061
C   -2.803  1.409   0.008
```

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;


my $search_text = qr/ATOM/;

my @fullpath= <*/*.pdb>;

foreach my $file (@fullpath) {
    print $file . "\n";

    my $dir = dirname($file);

    for (my $i=1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        open(DATA, $file);      
        open(out_file, ">", "$dir/$i.log") or die "Failed to open $dir/$i.log: $!";
    }

    while (my $line = <DATA>) {
        my @fields = split /\s+/, $line;
        if ($line =~ m/$search_text/) { 
            print out_file join("\t", @fields[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
        }
    }
}
close(out_file);
```

Comment: I don't know why you say you get two log files in each folder. You get 10. For each folder, for each number from 1 to 10, you create a log file. Why do you have a loop if you want to create just one file? Get rid of the loop!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a new output file for each subfolder under a main folder using perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554352/how-can-i-create-a-new-output-file-for-each-subfolder-under-a-main-folder-using)

Comment: Are the values in your pdb files always less than ten?

Comment: No. My pdb files can have 50,60 or 100 values sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you have an inner `foreach` loop that opens the input file nine times (`$i` is 1 .. 9 because of the `< 10` criterion) and nine different output files, and this is happening for *every* `.pdb` file found.

You need a file-scoped counter to ensure that you name each log file differently.

You may also find it useful to consider these points

- It's best to restrict the import list of external modules as far as possible. By default, [`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Basename) exports `fileparse`, `fileparse_set_fstype`, `basename`, and `dirname`. You want only one of these, so you should write

  ```
  use File::Basename qw/ dirname /
  ```
- I have mentioned this loop already

  ```
  for (my $i=1; $i < 10; $i++) { ... }
  ```

  but in addition you should remember that most accomplished Perl programmers use `for` instead of `foreach` to reduce noise (they are identical in every way except their spelling). And if all you want is a range of numbers then you should use the *range operator* instead, like this

  ```
  for my $i (1 .. 9) { ... }
  ```

  The cases where a C-style for loop are very rare.
- You shouldn't use the `DATA` file handle as it has a built-in purpose. In fact you should use *lexical file handles* everywhere, like this

  ```
  open my $out_file, '>', "$dir/$i.log"
  ```

  But well done for choosing the three-parameter form of `open`
- If your processing is brief and straightforward then it is best to leave the `<>` operator to perform its default behaviour of putting each line into `$_`. That makes `chomp`, `split`, `print`, regex matches, and others much more concise and therefor more readable.

I believe this program does what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw/ dirname /;

my $search_text = qr/ATOM/;

my $infile_number;

while (my $infile = glob '*/*.pdb') {

    ++$infile_number;
    my $dir = dirname($infile);
    my $outfile = "$dir/$infile_number.log";
    print "$infile => $outfile\n";

    open my $in_fh,  '<', $infile  or die qq{Failed to open "$infile" for writing: $!};
    open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die qq{Failed to open "$outfile" for writing: $!};

    while (<$in_fh>) {
      next unless /$search_text/;
      my @fields = split;
      print $out_fh join("\t", @fields[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

> *"The columns in log file aren't ordered like columns in .pdb files. The point/dot of decimal numbers in .log files isn't top and bottom like in .pdb files. There is this problem when minus and plus decimal numbers are top and bottom."*

I think you mean that the decimal points aren't *aligned* in the same column. This variant of my original program will fix that. But are you sure you want to use tab characters between the columns? Tabs are usually used so that computers can separate the columns correctly, and aren't much use in documents that are meant for people to read.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename qw/ dirname /;
use Scalar::Util qw/ looks_like_number /;

my $search_text = qr/ATOM/;

my $infile_number;

while (my $infile = glob '*/*.pdb') {

    ++$infile_number;
    my $dir = dirname($infile);
    my $outfile = "$dir/$infile_number.log";
    print "$infile => $outfile\n";

    open my $in_fh,  '<', $infile  or die qq{Failed to open "$infile" for writing: $!};
    open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile or die qq{Failed to open "$outfile" for writing: $!};

    while (<$in_fh>) {
      next unless /$search_text/;
      my @fields = split;
      for (@fields) {
        $_ = sprintf '%6.3f', $_ if looks_like_number($_);
      }
      print $out_fh join("\t", @fields[2,6,7,8]), "\n";
    }
}
```

**output**

```
O   -4.657  -0.947  -1.014
N   -0.173   0.679   0.052
N    3.135  -0.678  -0.977
N    3.331   0.341   1.198
N    1.046  -0.695  -2.103
C   -1.086  -0.167   0.546
C   -2.430   0.177   0.537
C   -3.476  -0.737   1.080
C    1.209   0.327   0.061
C   -2.803   1.409   0.008
```

Comment: `@Borodin` thnx for your help. The code works excellently. But i have a little problem more. The columns in log file aren't ordered like columns in .pdb files. The point/dot of decimal numbers in .log files isn't top and bottom like in .pdb files. There is this problem when minus and plus decimal numbers are top and bottom. I used `sprint` instead of `print` but the result is the same. What is your recommend?

Comment: @perlselami: The output data is derived directly from the input data so I don't see how it can be ordered differently. If I understand you correctly then this new problem is unrelated to your original question, so I think you should open a new question and show your code and your input data together with the output you expect as well as the output you are actually getting.

Comment: @perlselami: If you are using `sprintf` then my guess is that you're saving the lines in a hash and printing it at the end of the program. Is that correct?

Comment: `@Borodin`I am using `printf`. I used only `sprintf` to see whether the results are change or not. How can i send you a input and a output file?

Comment: You can look at the input and output file: 
Input file :[http://i.imgur.com/oHSjuqi.png]
Otput file: [http://i.imgur.com/F5Rh7dm.png]

Comment: Thank you, but I can't really use images as there isn't an easy way to convert them to text. You could put your files on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or just edit them into your question.

Comment: `@Borodin` thanks for your valuable helps. Now it works as i want exactly.And i have to use tab characters between the columns because these .log files will be the input files for another software. That software needs to these tabs between columns. Thanks again.

Comment: @perlselami: If this is for input to other software then you should use the *first* version. There is no reason to align the decimal points, and the additional spaces before the number that make it look nice are likely to upset the program that is reading it. If you find that it works as it is then your secondary program is probably just splitting on whitespace, and it would have been better to avoid tab characters altogether.